# Download android 4.1 source code on Ubuntu, have downloaded 15G but it is not finished

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-source

I am downloading the source code of android via Ubuntu 12.04. And the manifest file is :

```
<default revision="refs/tags/android-4.0.1_r1" remote="aosp" sync-j="4"/>
```

So I am downloading android 4.0.1. But the things is I have downloaded 15G, but it is not finished yet. I searched on the internet and it seems that the source code of 4.0 is not that big..

There is something wrong with the school's internet(sometimes the internet disconnects), so it often stuck like this and I need to stop it and repo sync again. Will this has anything to do with the result?
[image]

Comment: May be firewall problem.

Comment: write a script to auto-repo sync on a failure.

Comment: @JoxTraex Thank you. I've done that. The point is I really don't understand how the source code can be that big..

Comment: The android source is HUGE, I think i've had source as big as 20-25+ GB.

Comment: @JoxTraex Thank you. As long as it is not downloading the same file again and again, it will be fine....  But it seems that in the'Receiving objects' it is receiving the same files every time I repo sync it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repo tool not only download files of the selected branch of Android but also downloads all git history. So as any change of file in git creates a snapshot of this file, not surprisingly that with the lapse of time the sources grow. When I started to program Android with Gingerbread version the size of all the sources was less then 10 Gb. Now they are huge.

As for repo synchronization, as far as I remember, unless you successfully downloaded the whole project within repo, the repo tool will restart its synchronization. For instance, there is a subproject "frameworks/base", which is quite huge, thus, if the connection was lost during the synchronization of this subproject, you will be required to synchronize it once again. This can be the reason you see the same files loaded. However, I'm not sure in such behavior of repo tool.